# Upload a file to Drive without the browser popup using Python

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api

I'm working on automating a file upload on Google Drive, if it has been modified since the last modified date.

I'm using the Google Drive API to upload this file, and it works just fine. But whenever I execute the code, it always opens up a browser popup which takes to me Google account permission to allow the application to upload the file to drive.

```py
def uploadFile():
    # Setup the Drive v3 API
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
    #creds = store.get()
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
    folder_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    file_metadata = {'name': 'file.name',
    'mimeType': '*/*',
    'parents': [folder_id]}
    media = MediaFileUpload('filename.ext',mimetype='*/*',resumable=True)
    file1 = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    print ('File ID: ' + file1.get('id'))
```

I'm looking to automatically (without the browser popup) upload the file to the Drive in that specific folder. Can you tell me what am I missing?

Comment: usually API can ask only once for credentials and you can save them to file and use again when you start script next time.

Comment: you should check code in Google Drive API documentation: [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python). You have to save tokens in pickle to load them next time. If it loads tokens then it doesn't ask for credentials again.

Comment: you need a "Refresh Token"

Comment: @furas: In the code, I am loading creds using the pickle.load (the file is present in the directory as well). It still pops up a window for authorization.

Comment: you never save pickle so it has nothing to load and it has to ask for new credential

Comment: Solution suggested by @pinoyyid works ! I used the refresh token to upload the file seemlessly! Thanks.

Comment: @furas: I have the pickle file already saved in the directory beforehand. It should have loaded it in the first 'if' statement itself. Will check out why it was not happening. However, pinoyyid's solution works ! Thanks.